# scanf in do-while loop

Tags: c, scanf, do-while

I was wondering why does my scanf keep going when I just ask for two parameters?

```
do {
    scanf("%f %f\n", &a,&b);
    printf("a=%f; b=%f;\n",a,b);
    printf("f(a)=%f; f(b)=%f; f(a)*f(b)=%f;\n",f(a),f(b),f(a)*f(b));
}
while(a>=b || f(a)*f(b)>=0);
```

---

```
1
2
3
a=1.000000; b=2.000000;
f(a)=-3.281718; f(b)=-0.610944; f(a)*f(b)=2.004947;
1 5
a=3.000000; b=1.000000;
f(a)=10.085535; f(b)=-3.281718; f(a)*f(b)=-33.097884;
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%f %f \n ", &a,&b);
```

The \n at the end makes the scanf ignore the first newline character which would have otherwise terminated input.

This will work fine :

```
  scanf("%f %f ", &a,&b);
```

Comment: If this was helpful, then select it as the correct answer to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

remove \n from scanf.
scanf("%f %f", &a,&b);